# How to automate a azure table creation from one subscription to another subscription environment

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-table-storage

I'm having a subscription named as "abc" and in that having storage table with 4 columns which is for development environment.
For test and production environments, we have different subscriptions in azure portal.
My scenario is, I don't want to create a storage table manually again in test and production environments.
I expect to take this table schema as template from development environment and have to create it in test and production environment by passing subscription key, resource group name, storage account access key automatically.

How can I achieve it.

Comment: I am not sure if azcopy sync works for Azure Storage tables but it works pretty well with blobs. When you run azcopy sync command it syncs the files from source to destination.It  overrides the changed one. It can help you to replicate production anytime even if production table changes..

Comment: Do you just want to create the table or do you want to copy the data as well?

Comment: @GauravMantri: I just want to create table.

Answer (score 0):

Considering Azure Tables are schema-less, simply creating the table will do the trick for you. You don't really have to worry about the schema.

Assuming you're using [`Azure CLI`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/?view=azure-cli-latest) for automation, these are the steps you would need to follow:

1. Get storage account keys for the test/production storage account. You can use [`az storage account keys list`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/account/keys?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_account_keys_list) for that.
2. Once you have the storage keys, you will pick one of the keys (anyone will do) and then create a table in that storage account using that key. You can use [`az storage table create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/table?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_table_create) to create the table.